# How to Export HTML page in Excel Using PHP

Tags: php

I want to export my web page in excel file. below code -

```
<?php
$file="My_Excel.xls";
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms_excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
?>
```

Not working please suggest.

Comment: please share the code and error you are currently facing for others to be able to help you

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does it cause an error in the browser? An error on your server? An error in Excel? Your computer to catch fire?

Answer (score -1):

Right Code is -

```
<?php
$file="My_Excel.xls";
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
?>
```

Comment: This appears to be the same code as in the question.